# UITextField not responding to onscreen keyboard presses?

Tags: uitableview, keyboard, uitextfield, uialertview, first-responder

I've got a really weird problem whereby I when I click on a `UITextField` the onscreen keyboard pops up, and I can delete characters in the text field - but I cannot type into it!

Background info:

I'm placing the `UITextField` into a `UITableViewCell`, which in turn is being got from a table that is being placed into a `UIAlertView`. I still have the same problem if I place the `UITextField` directly into the `UIAlertView` using the `UIView addSubview:` method.

I have managed to write a `UIAlertView` in the past that has a `UITextField` within it working correctly.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the problem still occurs when adding the text field directly?  I have the same problem, but only when there is at least one view in the hierarchy between the text field and alert.

Comment: Haha! Yes it always helps to get someone to make you double check! It works when I add it as a subview, so I suppose I should just position the UITextFields so as they're above the cells as a work around.
Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found in comments under the question.